# I'm receiving a segmentation fault in x86 that I don't understand

Tags: assembly, x86, segmentation-fault, x86-64

I have this assembly program that takes three arguments (pointer to an int array, the size, and a target) and need to program a linear search, but in every instance that I've tried, I keep receiving segmentation fault.

```
    section .text

; function should return the index at which the target was found

; Parameter 1 is a pointer to the int array
; Parameter 2 is the size of the array
; Parameter 3 is the target element to find in the array

linearSearch:
    push rbx        ; int i[] (the array)
    push r12        ; int j (array.size())
    push r13        ; int k (the element to find)
    xor r10, r10        ; pointer to an index of the array
    xor r14, r14        ; count to keep track of size searched
    xor rax, rax        ; initialize rax as 0 to avoid random nonsense
    jmp loop        ; head into loop to find element

    mov r14, 0      ; initialize count as 0
    mov r10, rbx        ; r10 = first element of i[] 

loop:
    cmp r14, r12        ; count >= j ? jmp end : continue
    jae endNotFound     ; jump to int not found end
    cmp r10, r13        ; i[r10] == k ? je end : continue
    je end          ; jump to int found end
    inc r14         ; increase counter for amount searched by one
    mov r10, [rbx+4*r14]    ; set index pointer equal to r14+1 (4 being the size of int in 64-bit)
    jmp loop        ; rinse and repeat

endNotFound:
    mov rax, -1     ; by convention, return -1 if the int cannot be found
    pop r13
    pop r12
    pop rbx
    ret
end:
    mov rax, r10        ; move index pointer to rax to be returned  
    pop r13
    pop r12
    pop rbx
    ret
```

Initially, I thought the problem was that I was having some kind of random variable issue, so I initialized the non parameter variables to 0 with xor, but still received the same error. What is it that I'm missing? Or better yet, what conceptually am I forgetting that keeps causing these segmentation faults, because this isn't the first time I've run into this issue and it's likely the same thing.

Comment: `mov r10, [rbx+4*r14]` is loading 8 bytes not 4, but that should not be the cause of the fault (unless you are very unlucky). Your calling convention seems strange are you sure the input arguments are in `rbx`, `r12` and `r13`? Use a debugger to find out the point of the crash, then examine registers and trace backwards what caused the problem. This is not a `[mcve]`. I have added a caller and it does not crash, even though it does not find the element. Fixing the `r10` problem it works. Note the return value is the item found not a pointer. Maybe your caller is dereferencing it?

Comment: `[mcve]` should have been [mcve].

Comment: Why wasn't it? [mcve] Strange, works here. Maybe too long comment?

Comment: @Jester: You got carried away with backticks and put `[mcve]` inside backticks in the first comment, so it got literal code formatted instead of expanding as markdown.  There's no length limit: I've had comments that were exactly 600 characters including the 6-byte [mcve] markdown.